# Deque custom cells from specific indexpath SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have UICollectionView, I am downloading images and displaying them in the cells. My first cell is of screen width and contains a button, rest are the general cells. The application only deques the first 2 cells, There are supposed to be 3 cells.

My `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        print("yay")
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UploadNewCell", for: indexPath) as! UploadNewCell
        return cell
    }else if indexPath.row > 0 {
        let userImages = userposts[indexPath.row]
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileCell
            cell.fillCells(uid: uid!, userPost: userImages)
            return cell
    }else{
        return ProfileCell()
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        print("hellowold")
    } else {
        let selecteditem : String!
        selecteditem = userposts[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "lol", sender: selecteditem)
    }
}
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userposts.count


}
```

my view:

[image]

There are supposed to be 3 images down there in the cells, One of them is dequed in the first index.

I am out of Ideas, Any ideas on the solution?

Comment: "When ever I select the cell on the first index, It doesnt responds as expected." Where is that code?

Comment: @Larme Update the question and query. The cell selection behaves fine now. Dequeing the cell is an issue. See question again. Sorry for the error in asking.

Comment: Number of items in sections returns...?

Comment: Sorry, I am facing an issue in  my machine. The code is updated now. Thanks for bearing.

Comment: return userpost.count+1 in  number of items in section

Comment: doing that returns an error : `Index out of range`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `let userImages = userposts[indexPath.row]`

At this point in your code, `indexPath.row` is > 0.
Arrays are 0-based, so the first cell (`indexPath.row == 1`) is getting the second item in your array (`user posts[1]`), which is the second image you wanted.

I can think of a couple of simple changes:

- Change the index you're accessing, such as:
  `let userImages = userposts[indexPath.row - 1]`
- Add 1 to your `userposts.count` value in `numberOfItemsInSection:`
- Split your collectionView into having multiple sections, so the top cell (`UploadNewCell`) is section 0, and the bottom three `ProfileCell`s are a second section: this allows you to check the `indexPath.section`, and assign directly from row:
  `let userImages = userposts[indexPath.row]`

---

Note: I would actually advise further modifying the code for the second option to create an enum for `SectionType`. That allows you to perform a `switch` over the potential values, allowing you to avoid that nasty default implementation, and boosts the readability of your code.

Comment: this is perfect thanks. I was just adding +1 to the index. My bad. This is apt answer. Thanks for prompt reply. Cheers

Comment: and Also, I was just trying out the section part. I aswell think, Enum will be a better option to eliminate nasty errors in future